# Converting uppercase to lowercase with hyphen

Tags: python, string, list

I'm processing some CSS code using Python, since they came from a JSON file (JSON doesn't accept hyphens) they have a particular notation `eg.. font-size = fontSize`, I'd like to convert every uppercases letter and put them back in the right CSS format inserting a hyphen right before the uppercase.

```
string = 'borderRadius: 0px, zIndex: 2, transform: translate(170px, 195px) skew(-30deg, 0deg), fontSize:30px'

def getIndices(string):
    // get position of each capital letters.
    index = [i for i, c in enumerate(string) if c.isupper()] 

    // code below would be inserted here.

    // insert hyphen right before the upperscase
    for i in index:
        string = string[:i] + '-' + string[i:]

    // once done, set string to lowercase since there are no uppercases in CSS properties
    string = string.lower()
    return string

getIndices(string)
```

The issue is that each time a hyphen is insered, the position of capital letters becomes off hence the insertion are off too.

I thought about enumarting the index and increasing each int in list by their index number, but I'm probably doing something not quite right.

```
...
index = [25, 35, 58]
for i, value in enumerate(index):
    value = value + (i)
    index[i] = value
```

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, this is one way of doing it

```
 for c in my_string:
      print c
      if c.isupper():
          my_string = my_string.replace(c,"-%s" % c.lower())

 print my_string # will print fontSize = font-size
```

Comment: The idea is smart and more efficiant than mine, I like it!

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do your insertions in reverse. Otherwise the first ones will change the offset of the last ones. This can be done by calling `reversed` on the index list before looping over it.

```
def getIndices(string):
    # get position of each capital letters.
    index = [i for i, c in enumerate(string) if c.isupper()] 

    # code below would be inserted here.

    # insert hyphen right before the upperscase
    for i in reversed(index):
        string = string[:i] + '-' + string[i:]

    # once done, set string to lowercase since there are no uppercases in CSS properties
    string = string.lower()
    return string
```

But it would be better to avoid:

```
string = string[:i] + '-' + string[i:]
```

As it makes four new strings every loop iteration.

By building a list and then calling `'-'.join`. The following works:

```
def getIndices(string):
    # get position of each capital letters.
    index = [i for i, c in enumerate(string) if c.isupper()] 

    # code below would be inserted here.

    # insert hyphen right before the upperscase
    l = []
    e = len(string)
    for i in reversed(index):
        l.append(string[i:e])
        e = i
    l.append(string[:e])
    l.reverse()
    string = '-'.join(l)

    # once done, set string to lowercase since there are no uppercases in CSS properties
    string = string.lower()
    return string
```

I'd like to do:

```
l = []
e = len(string)
for i, c in reversed(enumerate(string)):
   if c.isupper():
      l.append(string[i:e])
      e = i
l.append(string[:e])
l.reverse()
string = '-'.join(l)
```

[The code above does not work as it results in `TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence` but the error is misleading the argument must either be a sequence or an object that has `__reversed__` defined]

But when they added `reversed` they didn't think about making it applicable to all built-in iterator functions by defining `__reversed__` that returns the reverse they are iterating over an iterable that has a `__reversed__`. I've implemented an `enumerate` that works that way and find it Pythonic. Oddly it works on `xrange` but not on `enumerate` so the code becomes:

```
def getIndices(string):

    l = []
    e = len(string)
    for i in reversed(xrange(len(string))):
       if string[i].isupper():
          l.append(string[i:e])
          e = i
    l.append(string[:e])
    l.reverse()
    string = '-'.join(l)

    string = string.lower()
    return string
```